# How to access pointer members in a Struct variable in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm not new to C but I just found out a problem which I have to deal with.
How do I access the member of a struct that is a pointer to another struct?

ex.

```
typdef struct {
   int points;
} tribute;

typedef struct {
    int year;
    tribute *victor;
} game;

int main(){
  tribute myVictor;
  myVictor.points = 10;  

  game myGame;
  myGame.year = 1994; // Runs fine
  myGame.victor = myVictor; // I want to point the victor member of the game struct to 
                            //myVictor object... But it gives me an error
}
```

How could I correct this? I know that I should've made the myGame variable as a pointer.. but I'm asking if I can do this in a normal struct variable.

Comment: Haha, that got me.. I actually learned C years ago.. I just had to deal with it again now for a project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
myGame.victor = &myVictor;
```

Comment: Waaah.. I forgot. Thank you for your answer :D.. I'll check the answer once the time for check answers is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to do with structs as such. You are merely trying to copy a data variable into a pointer, which isn't valid. Instead of `myGame.victor = myVictor;`, let myGame.victor point to the *address of* myVictor.

`myGame.victor = &myVictor;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to point the victor member, you should pass the victor pointer (address, memory direction, ...).

So, it sould be:

```
myGame.victor = &myVictor;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typdef struct {
   int points;
} tribute;

typedef struct {
    int year;
    tribute *victor;
} game;

int main(){
  tribute myVictor;
  myVictor.points = 10;  

  game myGame;
  myGame.year = 1994; 
  myGame.victor = &myVictor; 
}
```

here `victor` is a `pointer` to `tribute` so you need to provide `address` of `myvictor` 
So error in the last line of your code here is the correct one

changed to this in the last line : `myGame.victor=&myVictor`

Answer (score 1):

victor of game struct is pointer. So you should assign the address of myVictor. Something like this:

```
myGame.victor = &myVictor;
printf("Points is: %d",myGame.victor->points);
```