# Access a pointer of a structure inside another structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

this is supposed to be a basic question in C programming but I am having a confusion in accessing a pointer of a structure placed inside another sturcture: I have the following two structures:

```
struct header{
char version;
Bucket *bucket;
};

struct Bucket{
int length;
};
```

Now, how do I access the structure Bucket variable "length" with the help of the header object head which is defined as

```
struct header head;
```

If it was a simple structure variable then I could access it by the *dot* operator but this is a pointer so can somebody please help me in it? Its a basic hierarchy of structures but I am having a big big confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access pointer members in a Struct variable in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082615/how-to-access-pointer-members-in-a-struct-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Simple use the `->` operator.
Note that you first has to set the `bucket` pointer to a valid value or you will probably get an access violation error.

For example:

```
struct header head;
struct Bucket bucket;
head.bucket = &bucket;

// then access it via head
head.bucket->length;
```

You can also manually allocate the bucket, but then you shall not forget to `free` it.

Also, you should define the `header` struct with `struct Bucket* bucket;` if you haven't already `typedef`'d bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
head.bucket->length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head
```

should be clear

`head.bucket`

gives you that pointer.
If you only have a pointer bucket, how would you access length?

```
bucket->length
```

Combination:

```
head.bucket->length
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with :

```
    head.bucket->length
```

Also in the declaration of your struct header it should be :

```
    struct Bucket *bucket;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the bucket pointer in the header struct with a `.`:

```
head.bucket
```

Now, bucket is a pointer, so access what it points to with `->`

```
head.bucket->length
```

Answer (score 0):

`head.bucket->length`

bucket is member of head so `head.bucket`, Now that member is pointer to a structure so `head.bucket->length`

Before using the `bucket` pointer, It should be initialised to a valied address.

```
Bucket B;
head.bucket=&B;
head.bucket->length=0;// Example statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use both dot and arrow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Bucket {
  int length;
};
struct header{
  char version;
  struct Bucket *bucket;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct header head;
  head.version = 'a';
  head.bucket = (struct Bucket *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct Bucket));
  head.bucket->length = 2;
  printf("%d\n", head.bucket->length);
  //delete head
};
```